# Activating classes with hangfire in ASP Net Core

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have issues with configuring HangFire. I'm trying to fire and forget an alarming call in ASP Net Core.

Alarming Service:

```
public void FireAndForgetAlarm(int statusCode, string message, string subject = null, IList<string> attachmentFilePaths = null)
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Alarm(statusCode, message, subject, 
    attachmentFilePaths));
}
```

*The Alarm method is public.

Error description:

> warn: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
> Failed to process the job 'eb7f76ea-7522-49e2-b7b9-3ed3ed091a0c': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 2 of 10 will be performed in 00:01:02.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Wms.Alarming.AlarmingConfig' while attempting to activate 'Wms.Alarming.AlarmingService'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
> at Hangfire.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
> at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
> at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0()
> at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2() at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
> at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
> at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)

My startup class contains:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureAlarmingServices(new AlarmingConfig()
    {
        Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPort"]), // for SSL 465
        Sender = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailSender"],
        SmtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"],
        Recipients = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailRecipients"],
        SenderPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
    });
    services.AddHangfire(c => {
            c.UseMemoryStorage();
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) 
{
     app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions(){Activator = new AspNetCoreJobActivator(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>())});
}
```

Notes:

- I have tried multiple versions for the startup class, including putting the activator in the AddHangire method. No attempt actually worked, and I followed the documentation properly too.
- The alarming service is properly configured, it works without HangFire.
- Passing literals in the alarming config does not work
- Only solution is making the method static, but this does not allow for nice DI
- I have seen a solution in their documentation where they would always have a default constructor and call the constructor with paramters. However, this is not possible for me as I'm also injecting the logger.

Content of extension method as requested in comments:

```
public static void ConfigureAlarmingServices(this IServiceCollection collection, AlarmingConfig config)
{
    collection.AddSingleton<IAlarmingService>(x=> new 
    AlarmingService(x.GetService<ILogger<IAlarmingService>>(), config));
}
```

Comment: Where's the code that actually throws the error? It seems like you've missing configuration for `FileStorageService`.

Comment: You are right @Xerillio I showed the alarming service as I also had an issue with the alarming service (the same). Let me update.

Comment: @Xerillio I updated the error message, the filestorageservice error message was my first one which I could solve by making it static. This alarmingservice however, can't be solved in that way.

Comment: Is `ConfigureAlarmingServices` a custom method? What's happening in that method? It seems like you're missing a `services.AddScoped<AlarmingService>(...)` or something similar.

Comment: yes it's an extension method where I register the alarming service as a singleton @Xerillio

Comment: Could you show the contents of it?

Comment: Added it to the bottom @Xerillio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the important part of the exception you are seeing is:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Wms.Alarming.AlarmingConfig' while attempting to activate 'Wms.Alarming.AlarmingService'

Which indicates that somewhere in your code (a part you haven't shown yet) you are trying to inject an instance of `AlarmingService`.

You've configured how to resolve a singleton service for the interface `IAlarmingService`, which means you should be able to have a class depend on `IAlarmingService`. However, if your class depends specfically on `AlarmingService` (not the interface), you will get this error, because you have not defined how to resolve a dependency of type `AlarmingService`.

Either...

- the code you haven't shown should only depend on `IAlarmingService` and not the concrete class itself (`AlarmingService`) or..
- you need to also configure DI container to handle a dependency specifically of type `AlarmingService`, e.g.:

```
public static void ConfigureAlarmingServices(this IServiceCollection collection, AlarmingConfig config)
{
    collection.AddSingleton<AlarmingService>(
        x => new AlarmingService(x.GetService<ILogger<AlarmingService>>(), config));
    collection.AddSingleton<IAlarmingService>(x => x.GetService<AlarmingService>());
}
```

I think the first point is what you need to fix.

Comment: Nothing depends on the concrete class, I use proper DI. The second statement is no different from the first, plus isn't valid as you get the IAlarmingService and try to register it as an AlarmingService. You gave me a new idea though, registering the config separately. That worked!

Comment: @wutBruh You're right, the service registration should have been swapped around. That's fixed now. I'm still wondering why you would need to register the config separately. That shouldn't be necessary when you define a factory for `IAlarmingService`. If you don't register the config and use my fixed code, does that still not work?

Comment: Ah it does work and I only see what you meant by that now. The library wants the actual implementation because that's where it's being executed, despite passing the interface. Makes sense.

Comment: One more question. Does it make any sense to enqueue a job that runs one single async method? Should I await it or not?

Comment: @wutBruh sure, why not? The number of methods you call don't matter. Whether to await or not I don't think makes a difference. As far as I can see Hangfire doesn't yet support true "asynchronousity".